# Why does member assignment fail in initializer list but not in the constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, initializer-list

I am writing code that follows the member dependency schemes discussed in:

[Resolve build errors due to circular dependency amongst classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes)

In it's simplest form, the code headers looks like this:

A.h

```
class B;
class A{
 public:
   A();
   void send(int i);
   B* b;
};
```

B.h

```
#include A.h
#include foo.h

class B : public foo{

 public:
  B(A *a);
  A *a;
  void send(int i); //this invokes a member function of a
};
```

Now, in my source code, if I use an initializer list that looks like:

A.cpp

```
A::A() : b(this){};
```

I get a compiler error saying "error: cannot convert ‘A* const’ to ‘B*’ in initialization

However, if I don't use an initializer list, and instead I use a new pointer declaration, it compiles fine:

```
A::A(){
b = new B(this);
}
```

Could anyone help me reason why the initializer list causes the compiler to misinterpret the class B constructor argument? Or maybe something else is happening?

Just in case it helps, here is the B.cpp file:

B.cpp

```
#include "B.h"
#include "A.h"

B::B(A *inst){
    a = inst;
}

void B::send(int i){
    a->send(i);
}
```

Comment: `this` in the constructor of A will refer to the instance of A, not an instance of B, hence the error. You still have to create the instance of B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your assignment:

```
b = new B(this);
```

you are constructing a `B` object from `this`, and assigning a pointer to this object to `b`. You need to do the same thing in your member initializer list:

```
A::A() : b(new B{this}){};
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's remove the noise and minimize your example:

```
struct A;
struct B { B(A*) {} };

struct A {
    A() : b(this) { }; // error: cannot convert 'A*' to 'B*' in initialization
    B* b;
};

int main() {}
```

The data member `b` of `A` is of of type `B*` rather than `B`, and we can minimize the example even further:

```
struct A {};
struct B { B(A*) {} };

int main() {
    A a{};
    A* pa = &a;
    B* pb{pa};  // error: cannot convert 'A*' to 'B*' in initialization
}
```

The error message is now quite explanatory (given the simple context): we simply cannot

- initialize a *pointer* to `B` by a pointer to `A`.

The constructor of `B` is not relevant here, as it provides a way to:

- initialize an *object* of type `B` by a pointer to `A`.

The `new` operator, however, dynamically creates object *and returns a pointer to it*, meaning that the following:

```
B* pa{new B(pa)};
```

is:

- initializing a pointer to `B` by a pointer to B which *points to* an *object* of type `B` which was initialized by a pointer to `A`.